# Is there a chronology of exactly when the various Strikers quit?

Tags: atlas-shrugged, ayn-rand

According to the book, after John Galt decided to go on strike, he first went to Francisco D'Anconia and Ragnar Danneskjöld. As John Galt stated in his speech:

> It was the three of us who started what I am now completing. It was the three of us who resolved to avenge this country and to release its imprisoned souls.

Very early on, they also approached William Hastings (who had been John Galt's boss at the 20th Century Motor Company) and Hugh Akston (who had taught them at the Patrick Henry University). (William Hastings joined approximately a year later).

Richard Halley appears to have been a very early Striker, having already retired many years prior to the start of the novel.

Midas Mulligan and Judge Narragansett were also early Strikers. (In fact, Midas Mulligan was the one who established Galt's Gulch).

Can a complete timeline be derived from the book?

Comment: This would require a careful re-reading of the book, and some note-taking. I would also be very interested to see such a timeline!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did a quick scan of the book (online PDF) and I'm of the opinion that it's impossible to know for certain. I think we can know the sequence of the first and the last, but not most in the middle, because that information is never stated in the book.

The First:

1. John Galt
2. Ragnar, Francisco (maybe Hugh?)
3. Midas Mulligan

The Last (in reverse order):

1. Dagny
2. Hank

(And here my memory gets murky, but perhaps the Utah guy and Dannager)

But for those in the middle, the timeline is very murky.

Answer (score 1):

**Spoiler alerts**

Here's the order I could reconstruct (please feel free to edit with changes if I got anything wrong):

1. John Galt
2. Ragnar, Francisco, and possibly Hugh
3. Midas Mulligan and Judge Narragansett (both related to Judge Narragansett's ruling in the Lee Hunsacker lawsuit being overturned)
4. William Hastings quit about a year John Galt. (He worked for a different company in the interim after quitting at the 20th Century Motor Company, but his wife noted to Dagny that he seemed conflicted, and that he eventually retired to join the strike, although she was not aware of that because he asked her not to ask him why).
5. Richard Halley evidently quit somewhere in that general timeframe
6. Owen Kellogg quit towards the beginning of the book
7. Dick McNamara quit right before starting work on the John Galt Line
8. Andrew Stockton quit before he could deliver new engines for the John Galt Line
9. Ellis Wyatt
10. McNeil (only mentioned briefly as having quit in the aftermath of Directive 10-289; not mentioned anywhere else in the book)
11. I may have the order wrong on this, but Ken Dannager quit the night before his trial for making "illegal" transactions with Hank Rearden
12. Roger Marsh
13. Ted Nielson quit after the John Galt Line got shut down
14. Quentin Daniels
15. Hank Rearden, Gwen Ives, his mills superintendent, his company doctor, and numerous other individuals from his firm
16. Dagny Taggart (following the arrest of John Galt and destruction of the Taggart Bridge)

Dan Conway's company was ruined by the Anti-Dog-Eat-Dog Rule and quit, but he never joined the strike. It's unclear whether any of the strikers ever attempted to contact him.

I was unable to classify Lawrence Hammond.

The following characters I don't believe that the book gave enough information on to know (and correct me if I'm wrong): Kay Ludlow, Dr. Hendricks, the Fishwife, Dwight Sanders

Comment: Why did you accept the other answer if you can do better than that yourself? :-)